# About dual booting and formating

Tags: ubuntu, installation, multi-boot, formatting

I have a DELL laptop. By default it was installed with Windows 10 and then I dual booted Ubuntu 14.04 along side of Windows 10. Now I want to uninstall both the OS and install only latest Ubuntu 16. Please help me on this.

Comment: Remove all existing partitions, and install the OS you want.  Where are you getting stuck exactly?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Sorry, this is not a "step-by-step" instructional site. There are plenty of resources for that on the Internet. This is a Q&A site for specific questions when you have a problem. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. Like Charlie said, this is a very broad question so here's a quick and dirty overview-

Firstly, you could try updating and expanding your existing Ubuntu installation. Run

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

to upgrade the OS, use something like `gparted` to delete your Windows partition(s) and expand the one that Ubuntu is on, and then use `resize2fs` to expand your root filesystem. Done.

You could also try doing a fresh install from a live boot disk. Find an empty flash drive with at least 4gb of space(or, if your laptop is too old to boot from a flash drive, use a dvd). Download a copy of Ubuntu 16.04 from their website, use Ubuntu's Startup Disk Creator(or something like win32-disk-imager in Windows) to write the image to the drive, and boot from it. You should get a simple graphical installer with an option to overwrite both existing operating systems without you having to deal with partitions and stuff.

If you're doing a clean install, I would still recommend updating your existing release to 16.04 just to make sure that the hardware is compatible and there are no bugs. I've had release upgrades break the graphical drivers on two computers in the past. It's not pleasant.

If you need help on any particular stage, try posting a more specific question which explains exactly what it is that you are doing and where it is that you're stuck.